# How to get text from an image through google drive ocr

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

In google drive, An image or pdf file can be opened as Google Docs.
By this process, a google doc file is created with text from OCR.
It's a free process [ apart from Cloud Vision ]
How to get Text from an image?
please write code in python

Comment: see this for python tessract OCR https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/

Comment: sorry sir. I know about tessract .
But i want to know about google drive api

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/05/02/ocr-using-google-drive-api/

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai, I think Tesseract, does not do as much as Google OCR for all languages!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Drive API in Python you will need to get your project client secret and set the scopes to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. Download your client_secret.json file from your project and put its file location below in place of :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os
import io
from apiclient import discovery
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
CLIENTSECRET = "<client_secret_json_location>"
APPNAME = "AppName"

def authenticate():

    store = Storage(CLIENTSECRET)
    creds = store.get()
    pycheck = None

    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENTSECRET, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPNAME
        if pycheck:
            creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:
            creds = tools.run(flow, store)

    return creds
```

You can then call the API to upload the image and retrieve the OCR output. You can see the documentation for the MediaIoBaseDownload class [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload-class.html). The export_media() method exports to the requested MIME type and [returns exported content](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#export_media).

```
def main():
    creds = authenticate()
    http = creds.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build("drive", "v3", http = http)

    imgfile = "image.png"
    txtfile = "output.txt"
    mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document"
    requestBody = {
            "name": imgfile,
            "mimeType": mimeType
        }

    media = MediaFileUpload(imgfile, mimetype = mimeType, resumable = True)

    request = service.files().export_media(fileId = file["id"], mimeType = "text/plain")

    dl = MediaIoBaseDownload(io.FileIO(txtfile, "wb"), request)

    isComplete = False

    while isComplete != True:
        status, isComplete = dl.next_chunk()

    service.files().delete(fileId = file["id"]).execute()
    print("Image uploaded and OCR output saved to " + txtfile + ".")
```

Trying this code with [this image](https://cdn8.openculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/22140851/lorem-2-1024x443.png) outputs [this text file](https://pastebin.com/e2tete0r).

For further reading or for more understanding of OCR, the Cloud Vision API has dedicated Optical Character Recognition for Images, PDF/text files and handwriting. You can see this documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr).